# How to echo the url thats being used in curl command / How to make the returned Chinese characters readable?

Tags: php, curl, echo

1. How could I echo the url that I use to curl data from along with the data showed?
2. My server does not display the Chinese characters properly from this curl, How can I fix it?

```
function mobile_number(){

        $tel = isset($_GET['tel'])?$_GET['tel']:’';

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://tcc.taobao.com/cc/json/mobile_tel_segment.htm?tel=' . $tel);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);


        print_r($resp); 
    }
```

This the result I get back:

```
__GetZoneResult_ = { mts:'1357465', province:'����', catName:'�й��ƶ�', telString:'13574652375', areaVid:'30514', ispVid:'3236139', carrier:'�����ƶ�’ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a problem with whatever you're using to view the results.

for example, if you're using a web browser to view the results, then the problem is that you're not telling the web browser to interpret it as unicode, and your browser try to interpret it as ASCII or something, in which case the fix is to add

`header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8");` at the top of your script.

if you're using a terminal.. idk, maybe try using a better terminal? bash maybe?

PS, you're vulnerable to variable injection and variable corruption on line 6 (for example the number `+47123123` would be converted to `47123123`, the + would be lost!) the code should be

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://tcc.taobao.com/cc/json/mobile_tel_segment.htm?tel=' . urlencode($tel));
```

Comment: This has fixed the problem. Thanks.
header("Content-Type: application/javascript;charset=GBK");

Comment: @mamachichi if it is a legacy codebase, sure keep your GBK, but for any modern codebase, you should use UTF-8 everywhere, not GBK :) there's literally a wall of good reasons to use UTF-8, check this website: https://utf8everywhere.org/